# After update on 18.4 I get "ssh: couldn't resolve hostname error"

Tags: ssh, dns, hostname

Last week I got an update for Linux 18.04 and after that, I couldn't SSH into anything and I got:

```
ssh: Could not resolve host-name: Name or service not known
```

I used aliases to SSH into stuff I needed and I did not change it for weeks.

It looks like something changed with regards to my host-name but I am not sure what changed and where to look at. I checked the host-name list in `etc/hosts` and there is my host-name with correct IP.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is is just `ssh` which can't resolve hostnames? Can you `ping` an host (by name, not IP address)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `host HOSTNAME` and `host HOSTNAME 8.8.8.8` where you replace `HOSTNAME` with the actual host name (not the local alias) of the SSH server? If you’re unsure what it is look at your `~/.ssh/config` and/or the output of `ssh -v ALIAS` (where `ALIAS` is the host alias in question). Thanks.

Comment: my colleagues in the office can ssh into stuff that i can't with no problem so it must be something locally on my machine. this is output from ssh -v 

OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n 7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/kristijan/.ssh/config 
debug1: /home/kristijan/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for * 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * 
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known –